# How can I get adjacent intervals in a sequence

Tags: sequence, intervals, cplex, cp

I define a dvar of interval to represent a leg between two cities, and a dvar sequence on the interval. rightnow, i want to punish the following condition: if the destination city of a interval is not the departure city of it's next interval, then I count 1 in a variable, for example, named it as countVar. and I will minimize the countVar in the objective. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use typeOfNext to do what you need. Let me give you a small example. That way, you could compute countVar:

```
    using CP;

    range R = 1..6;

    dvar interval tia[i in R] size i;
    dvar sequence seq in all(i in R)tia[i] types all(i in R)i;
    dvar int typeOfNextResult[i in R];

    subject to {
      noOverlap(seq);
      
      // computing typeOfNextResult
      forall(i in R) typeOfNextResult[i]==typeOfNext(seq,tia[i],-1,-2);
    }

    execute {
      writeln(seq);
      writeln(seq.first() );
      writeln(seq.next(seq.first() ) );
      writeln(seq.last() );

      writeln("loop");
      var s=seq.first();
      for(var i in R)
      {
       writeln(s);
       s=seq.next(s) ;
      }
      writeln(s);
      
      writeln("typeOfNextResult=",typeOfNextResult);
    }
```

which gives

```
{<"tia[1]" 0 0 1 0 1 1>
     <"tia[2]" 1 1 2 1 3 2>
     <"tia[3]" 2 2 3 3 6 3>
     <"tia[4]" 3 3 4 6 10 4>
     <"tia[5]" 4 4 5 10 15 5>
     <"tia[6]" 5 5 6 15 21 6>}
 <1 0 1 1>
 <1 1 3 2>
 <1 15 21 6>
loop
 <1 0 1 1>
 <1 1 3 2>
 <1 3 6 3>
 <1 6 10 4>
 <1 10 15 5>
 <1 15 21 6>
null
typeOfNextResult= [2 3 4 5 6 -1]
```

Comment: thanks lots for your kind help. :) another question : I noticed you use seq.first() to get the first interval in OPL script. how can i get the first interval in a sequence in OPL, not in OPL script.

Comment: Hi, you could write "first(seq,tia[3]);" in order to say that tia[3] is the first interval in sequence seq.

Comment: first(seq,tia[3]) is constrains an interval variable to be the first in a sequence. I means If i want make sure the first interval have some special attributes (for example, the travel present by the first interval must start from a specific city), how can i get the first one.

Comment: Dear Alex， here is my OPL program, the key problem is how to describe the objective? would you like to help me to figure it out. Thanks a lot

Comment: using CP;
tuple flightLeg{
 key int LegID;
 int departurePoint;
 int destinationPoint;
 int aircraftID;
};
{flightLeg} Legs=...;
tuple aircraft{
 key int aircraftID;
 int aircraftType;
} 
 {aircraft} aircraftSet=...;
 
tuple stop {
 int LegID1;
 int LegID2;
 int stopTime;
} 
{stop} stopTimes=...;

Comment: dvar interval invFlighttasks[i in Legs][j in aircraftSet] optional  
  size 10;
 
dvar sequence seqAircrafts[i in aircraftSet] in 
 all(j in Legs) invFlighttasks[j][i] types 
 all(j in Legs) j.LegID;
 
//minize the number of disconnect (means the destinationPoint of a interval
//is not the departurePoint of it's next interval)
subject to {
 forall (i in aircraftSet)
      noOverlap(seqAircrafts[i],stopTimes);
    
}

Answer (score 0):

//Here is the CPLEX program

```
using CP;
tuple flightLeg{
key int LegID;
int departurePoint;
int destinationPoint;
int aircraftID;
}
{flightLeg} Legs=...;
tuple aircraft{
key int aircraftID;
int aircraftType;
}
{aircraft} aircraftSet=...;
tuple stop{
    int LegID1;
    int LegID2;
    int stopTime;
}
{stop} stopTimes=...;
dvar interval invFlighttasks[i in Legs][j in aircraftSet] optional  
        size 10;
dvar sequence seqAircrafts[i in aircraftSet] in 
    all(j in Legs) invFlighttasks[j][i] types 
    all(j in Legs) j.LegID;
//minize the number of disconnect (means the destinationPoint of a interval
//is not the departurePoint of it's next interval)
subject to {
    forall (i in aircraftSet)
      noOverlap(seqAircrafts[i],stopTimes);
}
```