# CPLEX OPL problem how to schedule even/odd time tasks

Tags: cplex, opl

Let's assume we have 10 tasks t0, t1, ... t9 for sake of simplicity and let's ignore dependency between tasks for sake of simplicity.

I have an OPL problem where I have to schedule the first task on an even time (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...). Second task must be after first task and odd time (1, 3, 5, ...). 3rd even, 4th odd, 5th even, and so on. First task won't necessarily be at 0 because there are actually other tasks.

If I can grab task Intervals sorted and then say something like Mod(t[i+1]-t[i],2) == 1 in the subject to that should work. How would I do something like that?

```
int Max = 4;
{string} TaskNames = {t0,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9};


// Other intervals and sequences setup...

dvar Interval taskIntervals [t in TaskNames] size 1;

dvar sequence taskSequences in taskIntervals;

subject to {
   //Other constraints and constraint to prevent overlap of TaskIntervals is already setup here

   //I need to loop through the intervals of the taskSequences except last one then
   //(startofNext(taskSequences, t, 0) - t)  % 2 == 1

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I think most of the answers misunderstood something. The constraints don't guarantee t0 is before t1. This means that I can get different position and declared position in the sequence which would make Prev or Next (which are based on position) output out of order.

What I used is the [isomorphism](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cpo.help/refcppcpoptimizer/html/isomorphism.html) constraint. Basically, this constraint does a 1-to-1 correspondence between two sets. The first set is my task set. The second set is based on @Alex Fleischer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62988632/cplex-opl-problem-how-to-schedule-even-odd-time-tasks#answer-62990707). CPLEX will then force the first set to follow the same pattern as the second set during optimization.

```
{string} TaskNames = {t0,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9};


dvar Interval taskIntervals [t in TaskNames] size 1;

int n=10;
range r=0..n-1;
dvar interval itvs[r] size optional;

subject to {
  // other constraints for taskIntervals

  forall(i in r : i!=0) {
      startBeforeStart(itvs[i-1],itvs[i]);
      (startOf(itvs[i])-startOf(itvs[i-1])) mod 2==1;
  }
  isomorphism(taskInverals, itvs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could start with

```
using CP;

int n=10;

range r=0..n-1;

dvar interval itvs[r] size 1..100;

subject to
{
  forall(i in r:i!=0) startBeforeStart(itvs[i-1],itvs[i]);
  
  startOf(itvs[0]) mod 2==0;
  
  forall(i in r : i!=0) (startOf(itvs[i])-startOf(itvs[i-1])) mod 2==1-(i mod 2);
}
```

Comment: Lol I was looking at one of your answers to another post and then I clicked on your profile to see when was your recent post only to find you posted here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135658/how-can-i-get-adjacent-intervals-in-a-sequence

Comment: This wouldn't work. In my code, itvs[0] isn't actually the first interval. There are some other constraints already setup which will determine the order.
However, I need an additional constraint such as the consecutive intervals in a sequence has an odd distance. I need to loop through the sequence skipping the first or last interval I'll edit the post to show what I have so far. Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, if I can get the order of the intervals in the sequence, I would mod by 2 and make sure it is == to (i mod 2)

Comment: Hi, you could use https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/opltipsandtricks/blob/master/positionofintervalinsequence.mod in https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/tips-tricks-opl-cplex-alex-fleischer/ to get position of interval in a sequence

Comment: The script returns wrong position. It seems it would only work if you are guaranteed the order is 1 3 5 2 4. In my case, 1 and 3 don't overlap but either one could be first. When I look at the decision browser, the sequence has different position and declared position. Is there a way to get the declared position?

Answer (score 0):

For each task you could introduce an auxiliary integer variable `x` and then require that the starting time for the task is either `2*x` or `2*x + 1`, depending on whether you want even or odd starting time.

Comment: The issue is that I don't know which one will start at even and which one will start at odd. Otherwise I would have just looped through the integers.

Comment: More in https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=a2f06a00-3072-4828-955d-32fcb53686ca&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer#bma2f06a00-3072-4828-955d-32fcb53686ca

Answer (score 0):

If (as I understand) the sequence of tasks is not known a priori, I would consider a model like this one:

```
using CP;

int n=10;

dvar interval x [i in 0..n] size 1;
dvar sequence s in x;

subject to {
  noOverlap(s);
  forall(i in 0..n-2) {
    (endOfPrev(s,x[i],0) == 0) => (startOf(x[i]) % 2==0); // First task starts at even time
    // Then the delay between consecutive tasks alternates between even and odd
    ( (startOf(x[i])-endOfPrev(s,x[i],0)) % 2) + ((startOfNext(s,x[i],0)-endOf(x[i])) % 2)  == 1;
  }
  last(s, x[n]); // x[n] is a technical interval variable at the end of the sequence
}​
```

The first constraint in the 'forall' loop ensures that the first interval (the only one such that endOfPrev(s,x[i],0) == 0 ) starts at even time.
The second constraint ensures that the consecutive delays between tasks in the sequence alternates evens and odds.